# SQL calc total Price of Order

Tags: sql

I've following relations and I've to find the top 5 Orders with the highest sale in the first quarter of 2014. I can't figure out what's missing

My Solution:

```
SELECT TOP 5 OrderArticle.OrderId as Id,SUM(OrderArticle.Quantity*Article.Price) as Summe
FROM  OrderArticle

JOIN Article ON OrderArticle.ArticleId=Article.Id
JOIN "Order" ON OrderArticle.OrderId='Order'.Id
Group by OrderArticle.OrderId

ORDER BY Summe DESC
```

[image]

Comment: Do you get an error? Wrong results?

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem because `Order` is a reserved word.  Your best bet is to change the table name.  Your query looks like SQL Server, so square braces are the way to go:

```
SELECT TOP 5 oa.OrderId as Id, SUM(oa.Quantity * a.Price) as Summe
FROM  OrderArticle oa JOIN
      Article a
      ON oa.ArticleId = a.Id JOIN
      [Order] o
      ON oa.OrderId = o.Id
GROUP BY oa.OrderId
ORDER BY Summe DESC ;
```

Only use single quotes for string and date constants.